# Telegram bot api: sendPhoto do not render html

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm composing messages in this way

```
const reply_telegram = {
        "chat_id"               : MIRKO,
        "photo"                 : row.image_url,
        "caption"               : '<b>Wow</b>',
        "parse_mode"            : "HTML",
        "disable_notification"  : true,
}
```

For the goal of this question, focalize on

```
"parse_mode" : "HTML"
```

I am usng the `sendPhoto` instead of classic `sendMessage`.

> 1. Official docs state that I *can* use a `caption` and `parse_mode` in the `sendPhoto` method
> 2. I am actively using `sendMessage` with html content, and it's handled as HTML as I want

In short, the problem is that: message is sent, photo is delivered, caption text is printed under the photo, tags are not printed, *but the title is not bold* as I requested.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `this.title` looks like?

Comment: If this.title is 'wow', I send the caption param as `<b>wow</b>`. The bot accepts it, but it simply write `wow`

Comment: After       
 `"caption"               : '<b>Wow</b>'`
 you have omitted the comma. can you verify that this is not the problem?

Comment: @AntonioAltieri: thanks, but it was just an error when copying code into this question. In the code the command is present. I upvote your comment and modify the question, because the problem is still present

Comment: Try using &lt instead of < and &gt instead of > in the html tag.

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña: thanks but using entities instead of literals do not works, the &lt; and the &gt; are litterally rendered. I must simply wait for telegram to fix rendering probably.

Comment: Is working like its supposed, you have some mispell maybe? look at this link, just change your Token and chatid:
https://api.telegram.org/bot<YourToken>/sendPhoto?chat_id=<yourChatID>&photo=https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.479168030.1016/flat,550x550,075,f.u2.jpg&caption="<b>Hola</b>"&parse_mode=HTML

Comment: Did you try the link @realtebo?

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña: now it works, after some updates from Twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, July of 2019, seems that the problem is no more present. 
Probably Twitter has fixed it.